# Hiding a TreeNode from TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview

In my Program there's is a user right, I'm taking those rights from the user rights that I have saved in the SQL database to the `static` variables when user login to the system, I want to restrict user from clicking not allowed TreeNodes. So It's checking from the `static` variable values. In my Form Load, I wrote:

```cs
if (bl_Static.AddReq != true)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.RemoveAt(6);
}
```

But It's not working. Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: How do you populate the TreeView? Designer? Code? Have you thought about creating a _FlaggedEnum_ for the access levels/rights and populate the TreeView according to the permit of the current user?

Comment: Hi,  @JQSOFT Thanks for the comment. I'm populating the Treeview from the design and in the node double click event, I set the form to open when the certain node click.

Comment: Here is the story, in the user registration I have put several checkboxes for the rights, think there's a checkbox for the Access to the "Add Request". So When I click the checkbox and save it, that data saves in the SQL under the user right column as a Boolean value. So when the user Login to the system, I'm calling that boolean values and stores in the Static variables I created on the C # Class. So If that Stacic Add Request variable stores a value true for that user, then Treeview Add Request Node is shown to the user, otherwise, want to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the `RemoveAt` method of the wrong parent node so the target node 
won't be removed if it is not in the [TreeNodeCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection?view=netcore-3.1) of `treeView1.Nodes`.

To solve the problem, find the target node by it's unique key/name using the [TreeNodeCollection.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection.Find);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.1) method and check whether it is a root or child node to call the `Remove` method of the right collection:

```cs
if (!bl_Static.AddReq)
{
    var tarNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find("GetTheNameFromTheDesigner", true).FirstOrDefault();

    if(tarNode != null)
    {
        if (tarNode.Parent != null)
            tarNode.Parent.Nodes.Remove(tarNode);
        else
            treeView1.Nodes.Remove(tarNode);
    }
}
```